# What GPS dongle / device works with Windows 10 IoT and Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, gps

Are there any USB GPS dongles / devices for Raspberry Pi 2 that work with Windows 10 IoT Core? Alternatively, how about a Pi HAT using the I/O pins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well that is likely to turn into a question about how do I do Serial over USB really I suspect as that how most of them are configured.
>
> There are quite a few examples of connecting to Generic Serial over USB and the likely problems in other questions on this forum which my prove helpful.
>
> Serial connection GPS is you can use.
> For example: https://www.adafruit.com/products/746

Via https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0de82554-c086-4b98-abbe-95dc5c7432ca/what-gps-dongle-device-works-with-windows-10-iot-and-raspberry-pi-2?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: Don't see how this answers the question. It's basically a quote from a forum post that says google it.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with a UART (Serial) GPS device "U-blox Neo 6m". It comes with a different baud rate. I have worked on both "9600" baud and "115200" baud devices. Both work like a charm. By default, it is configured for NMEA protocol ([refer this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgOZLgaLa0g)).

**Connection: RPi2 <-> Ublox Neo 6m**

- Connect Rx line of GPS device with RPi2's UART0 Tx (Refer to the [RPi2 pinmap](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PinMappingsRPi2.htm))
- Tx line of GPS device with RPi2's UART0 Rx
- Vcc line of GPS device with RPi2's 3.3V
- GND line of GPS device with RPi2's GND

**Programming: Windows IoT - Serial Communication**
After connecting GPS device with your RPi2, you need to program Windows IoT to listen to the NMEA strings transmitted by Ublox Neo 6m. Refer Serial-UART code snippet described at the [Raspberry Pi 2 Pin Mappings](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PinMappingsRPi2.htm).

Make sure, you have set baud rate correctly, which should match with your Ublox Neo 6m's baud rate or else it won't work.

> You can find Ublox Neo 6m's baud rate which should be listed on seller's website. Most Ublox Neo 6m works on either 9600 or 115200 baud rate.